kdb/q How do I change all values of 0n in table column?
I am originally trying to save a table in kdb, but I was getting a type error:
q)save `:tbl.csv
'type
  [14] save `:tbl.csv
       ^

When I looked up the reason for why this might be the case, it turned out to be one specific column with a strange data type:
q)cols[tbl] where 1<(count distinct type each)each tbl cols tbl
,`NEW_COLUMN

q)metaa tbl
17335 rows; 83 cols
c                              k| t f a FIRSTROW
------------------------------ -| - - - -----------------------------
NEW_COLUMN                      | j

q)select distinct NEW_COLUMN from tbl
NEW_COLUMN
-------------
0N
`
`N

I am trying to understand what 0N is and how I can replace it with just `. Does anyone know how I can do this? I tried to select all rows with 0N but I get an error, which must be because it's some kind of null type:
q)select from tbl where NEW_COLUMN = 0N
'type
  [0]  select from tbl where NEW_COLUMN= 0N
                                         ^

Any help is much appreciated!

You have null long/integer 0N in the column which looks like it should be a symbol type.
tbl:([]NEW_COLUMN:(0N;`;`N));

Your query didn't work because it's a mixed-type column, to query for the null longs you would need to exact match on each entry
q)select from tbl where NEW_COLUMN~\:0N
NEW_COLUMN
----------


Which is also how you could replace the null longs with null symbol
q)update NEW_COLUMN:` from `tbl where NEW_COLUMN~\:0N
`tbl
q)meta tbl
c         | t f a
----------| -----
NEW_COLUMN| s

But ultimately you have to fix the logic upstream that is placing the incorrect null into the table in the first place, rather than fixing it after-the-fact
